# CSV file issue. I converted to integer but still get TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Tags: python, csv, operators, typeerror

I am having an error when performing a calculation involving data I read-in from a csv file. I have a csv file with 2 columns: a date, and a profit column. I have to add two columns to this file that will calculate month-to-month net change. Since reading-in data is a string I make sure to wrap the column in the int() function and assign to a variable. But when I run the code to calculate values it still thinks its a str-type.

I get TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

```
with open(csv_path, 'r') as csvfile:
     csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter =',')
     header = next(csvreader)
     
     # append 2 new columns to header row
     header.append('Net Change')
     header.append('Monthly Average Change')

     # loop through the csvfile row-by-row and convert columns. Only the profit column is number  data, I set variables equal to the row position and use numeric functions.
     
     for row in csvreader:
          month = row[0]
          profit = int(row[1])        # I wrap the int() function around this row to convert to int
          
          beginning_balance = 0
          ending_balance = 0

          for profit in row:
               if beginning_balance == 0:
                    beginning_balance = profit              # set the first $ value in file
                    ending_balance = profit                 

               elif beginning_balance != 0:
                   beginning_balance = ending_balance       # ending balance of prev month is new 
                   ending_balance = profit

               net_change = beginning_balance - ending_balance
               percent_change = net_change / beginning_balance

               # write the calculations to the added columns per row
               row.append(net_change)
               row.append(percent_change)
```

And the code fails at the net_change = beginning_balance - ending_balance part. It thinks I'm using strings in a math calculation. I brought in profit with the int() function. These should be numeric. What can I do?

Comment: You overwrote the `profit = int(row[1])` by later using `for profit in row:`.  Not sure what you are doing with that `for` loop as it is iterating over every column of the row, including the `row[0]` and `row[1]` already extracted as `month` and `profit` and due to the overwrite `profit` will be a string.

Answer (score 0):

`for profit in row` is actually looping through the month and profit where the month is a string, hence you got the error. You may try to replace `for profit in row` with a counter which will resolve your issue. The counter i and j is to indicate which profit row you are in.

`beginning_balance = 0` and `ending_balance = 0` can put outside the `for row in csvreader` to get correct calculations for `net_change` and `percent_change`.

Updated code as below. (=

```
with open(csv_path, 'r') as csvfile:
csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
header = next(csvreader)

# append 2 new columns to header row
header.append('Net Change')
header.append('Monthly Average Change')

# loop through the csvfile row-by-row and convert columns. Only the profit column is number  data, I set variables equal to the row position and use numeric functions.
i = 0
j = 0
beginning_balance = 0
ending_balance = 0

for row in csvreader:
    month = row[0]
    profit = int(row[1])  # I wrap the int() function around this row to convert to int
    i += 1

    if j < i:
        if beginning_balance == 0:
            beginning_balance = profit  # set the first $ value in file
            ending_balance = profit

        elif beginning_balance != 0:
            beginning_balance = ending_balance  # ending balance of prev month is new
            ending_balance = profit

        net_change = beginning_balance - ending_balance
        percent_change = net_change / beginning_balance

        # write the calculations to the added columns per row
        row.append(net_change)
        row.append(percent_change)

    j += 1
```